# Can you change the default network in gcloud?

Tags: gcloud

Is there an equivalent gcloud config setting to change the name of the default network and assign a default subnet? I've deleted the initially configured network named "default" so when I run command and `forget --network --subnet` I get: `resource...networks/default' was not found`

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-http-server-8080 --allow tcp:8080 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags http-server --description "Allow port 8080 access to http-server"
Creating firewall...failed.
```

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/dev/global/networks/default' was not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations

It's a reasonable request.

I recommend you submit a feature request using Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) specifically against [Cloud SDk](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143)